# How to create an enum on kuzzle admin console

Tags: elasticsearch, kuzzle

I'm trying to create an enum field from the admin console but I can't achieve it right
I went through Elasticsearch's documentation but I don't really understand everything.

```
"ville": { 
    "type": "enum",
    "typeOptions": {
      "values": ["Montpelier", "Paris", "Lmoges", "Grenoble", "Bordeaux", "Rodez"],
      "mandatory": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone guide me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not handle enum type.

As far as I understand you are trying to use the [Data Validation](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/advanced/data-validation/#advanced-validation) module. You cannot update a collection specifications (aka "validations") with the Admin Console but you will need to use the [collection:updateSpecifications](https://docs.kuzzle.io/core/2/api/controllers/collection/update-specifications/) API action.